# Run msinfo32 from cmd in language other than currently used in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, msinfo32

My Windows10 is displayed in Polish language.

English language pack is additionally installed in the system.

When I run **msinfo32** (from cmd or start menu), the output is also in Polish, which won't be useful for bug report sharing.I would like to see its output in English.

**Is there a way to launch a program in specific language on Windows10?**

Looking for something similar to unix's `LC_ALL=C` command, which forces the command output in english.

Comment: Take a look at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-settings-hangs-and-msinfo32-language/f34b85d6-eaec-4cf7-8af7-38d0481bde75

Comment: Thx @double-beep, but this is not the case.

Comment: What says `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language"`? Something like `Default 0415` and `InstallLanguage 0415` and `InstallLanguageFallback pl-PL`?

Comment: It says:
`InstallLanguage    REG_SZ    0415
InstallLanguageFallback    REG_MULTI_SZ    en-US
Default    REG_SZ    0415`

Comment: Has there been any success in your process?
I am currently trying to send my MSInfo to Ubisoft, but my Windows 10 generates it in Hungarian, and they keep spamming me with it being corrupted.
Is there a way to convert it to hungarian?

Comment: Ultimately I switched to english display language OS wide (and on all devices) to not experience situations like this anymore.